# How to use laravel sanctum without typical laravel /login

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream, vue-authenticate

I have been created PWA with NuxtJS,

then I'm going to use [sanctum package](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum), but I don't want to request to the typical Laravel /login route, because I have a customized api /login route which authenticates users with OTP, not by password!

So I'm wonder how can I use sanctum in this situation??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Sanctum's token based authentication to achieve this. All you have to do is add the `HasApiTokens` trait to your authenticable model and issue new tokens for it on a successful login. So you would have a route which will accept phone number or email and perform a login action. This would trigger the application to send OTP to the user. You have to store the OTP somewhere on the system. Then create another endpoint where user's can send back the OTP they received. This route will then check if the provided OTP matches the one on the system and issue a token to the user.

```php
$token = $user->createToken(<provide-a-token-name>);
```

Make sure to send back the plaintext token to the user using the `plainTextToken` function on the token instance. User's will need to add this token to requests as a bearer token in the `Authorization` header.